# How can I install an Android environment on my Ubuntu system?

Tags: android

I'm wondering if there's an environment for my Ubuntu to try out Android 3.0. I just WANT to!!!

Comment: This question is worded in such a way that it looks off-topic at first glance, even though I understand now what you're asking for and I know it's not. Does anybody have a better idea than I on how to edit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if you want to test another operating system (OS) or an application on another OS you use a virtualization program like Virtualbox or VMWare Player. Personally, I use [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) PUEL (Personal Use and Evaluation License) version. That will create a new computing environment on top of your running Ubuntu.

Then to test Android 3.0, you will need to install the [Android Software Development Kit (SDK)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and follow the instructions in the website.

This way, you will protect your host system from messing up while doing software testing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, Google Developers also has a version of Android LiveCD which works like the Ubuntu Live CD. I'm not sure however if the version of Android in the .ISO is Honeycomb already. Anyway, here's the page link http://code.google.com/p/live-android/

Answer (score 2):

You can download a linux version of the SDK [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and install it on ubuntu if you wish, though there is only a 32 bit version available at present for linux.

The site also list the steps to get it up and working on your pc.